# Can Sublime text do this?

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, ctags

I would like to switch from Komodo IDE to Sublime Text but these two things are holding me back:

- Can I CTRL+click on a function to get to its definition?
- Is there any decent PHP/WordPress debugging within Sublime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the ctags plugin:

https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags

It will give you the ability to click through the definitions and such. Rubymine and PHPStorm do this very, very well, but ctags will get pretty close.

Comment: Thanks, what about debugging?

Answer (score 2):

I think the 'Goto Anything' feature of Sublime Text is what you are looking for: http://www.sublimetext.com/

Answer (score 0):

Even better: [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) was ported from Komodo IDE. I use it regularly and find it to be pretty good.

A quick google search for "PHP debugger sublime text" yielded [SublimeXdebug](https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug)

Answer (score 0):

YES.

Please look for [bendras.co.uk blog post about Sublime Text 3 as C++ IDE by Paulius Zaliaduonis](http://www.bendras.co.uk/blog/2016-06-30%20Sublime%20Text%203%20as%20C++%20IDE). You will find how to do it for C++. I saw there are [Sublime PHP Companion](https://github.com/erichard/SublimePHPCompanion), and [XDebug Client](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Xdebug%20Client).

All packages should work on most platforms: Windows, Linux, iOS?